# Trouble Parsing Atom feed with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, atom-feed

I have an Atom feed like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<feed 
    xml:base="http://earthquake.usgs.gov/" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
    xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss">
  <updated>2009-10-12T14:47:25Z</updated>
  <title>USGS M2.5+ Earthquakes</stitle>
  <subtitle>Real-time, worldwide earthquake list for the past 7 days</subtitle>
  <link rel="self" href="/eqcenter/catalogs/7day-M2.5.xml"/>
  <link href="http://earthquake.usgs.gov/eqcenter/"/>
  <author><name>U.S. Geological Survey</name></author>
  <id>http://earthquake.usgs.gov/</id>
  <icon>/favicon.ico</icon>
  <entry>
    <id>urn:earthquake-usgs-gov:us:2009mra9</id>
    <title test='GOT IT'>M 5.3, Santa Cruz Islands</title>
    <updated>2009-10-12T12:44:40Z</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="/eqcenter/recenteqsww/Quakes/us2009mra9.php"/>
    <link rel="related" type="application/cap+xml" href="/eqcenter/catalogs/cap/us2009mra9" />
    <summary type="html"><![CDATA[<p>stuff...</p>]]></summary>
    <georss:point>-11.7295 166.3124</georss:point>
    <georss:elev>-60100</georss:elev>
    <category label="Age" term="Past day"/>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

And jQuery code like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.get('data/_7day-M2.5.xml', {}, function(xml){
    $(xml).find('entry').each(function(i){
      alert($(this).find("title").text());            // DOESN'T WORK (EMPTY)
      alert($(this).find("title").attr('test'));      // DOESN'T WORK ('undefined')
      alert($(this).find("id").text());               // WORKS
      alert($(this).find("georss\\:point").text());   // WORKS
    });
  });
});
```

But like the comments say, it doesn't find the `<title>` element in the `<entry>`, but happily finds other stuff.

Anyone any ideas why and how to overcome this?

Cheers

Comment: Does the problem occurs if title is `<title>M 5.3, Santa Cruz Islands</title>`?

Answer (score 1):

You have `</stitle>` instead of `</title>` as a closing tag. I guess that's the problem :).

Comment: +1 you answered before me LOL... I'm still rubbing the gook from my eyes :P

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this [jFeed: JavaScript jQuery RSS/ATOM feed parser plugin](http://www.hovinne.com/blog/index.php/2007/07/15/132-jfeed-jquery-rss-atom-feed-parser-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

you have a closing tag named stitle... (oops Alex Ciminian beat me to it... still waking up!)

```
<title>USGS M2.5+ Earthquakes</stitle>
```

just rename it, also to get to the second title you might need to find the entry first

```
alert($(this).find("entry").find("title").attr('test'));
```

Answer (score 0):

ther's no need to use Jfeed... also i guess Paul example is just a typo... what he means is some browser have issue pulling the content of that tag... i had the same experience on Safari... maybe tray using  **eq(0)**

```
alert($(this).find("title").eq(0).text());
```